# Include the result of a function in a Python string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, average

Trying to work through some beginners Python code.

I need to provide a string that given 3 numbers a, b, and c, states `The average is: XX`.

How do I incorporate `sum(a,b,c) / len(a,b,c)` into the output string?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) is your friend.

Comment: reduced the question to a more minimal load of information

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = [5, 4, 3, 4, 5]
avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)

print("Your average score: " + str(avg))
```

Did you mean this?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do, but I'm not starting with numbers, I'm starting with a string that looks like this:def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    assert is_number(a) and is_number(b) and is_number(c)